# Which version of Node.JS should I use?

Tags: node.js

The [Node.JS website](http://nodejs.org) says the current version is 0.10.26, but the [git repo](https://github.com/joyent/node) has much newer versions going up to 0.11.12.

- Is there something wrong with the later versions, are they unstable?
- Why does the website say 0.10.26 is the current version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Node.js wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-versioning-scheme):

> Odd versions are unstable, even versions are stable. v0.2 and v0.4 are even/stable. v0.3 and v0.5 are odd/unstable. The current stable series is v0.10.x. The next stable series will be v0.12.x. The stable branch takes bug fixes only - it does not change the JavaScript API, addon API, nor ABI (you don't have to rebuild modules after upgrading node with-in a stable branch).

You should use stable versions for production. The web site displays prominently and gives links to download the latest *stable* verson.

However, if you are trying to stay ahead of the curve and prepare for the *next* and yet unreleased stable version, then *testing* against an unstable version makes sense. This is why the unstable versions are *also* available to developers.

Comment: That's a nice version numbering system, I like it.